# Posting/sharing data to LinkedIn

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, share

I am new to Web API. Currently I am working on posting data to LinkedIn from my web API method in C#. I have already created sample app in developers.linkedin.com. I am able to get the code and the access token. but while posting data or getting profile data I am getting 401- unauthorized access error. Previously I was able to get data from linked in but now I am not. here is my code after getting access token.

I am getting error at `WebResponse webResponse = request1.GetResponse();`
In API usage page of the application I can see that POST Share usage increments every API call. I am asking for `rw_nus` permission from the user to write to his account.
Am I writing a wrong URL or need to send some more information in the call?
What URL should I use to get user profile. I was using "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~" this URL previously.

Is it possible to share image or video from my web application to LinkedIn?

Please help me to fix this issue.

```
string linkedinSharesEndPoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people     /~/shares";

WebRequest request1 = WebRequest.Create(linkedinSharesEndPoint);
request1.Method = "POST";
request1.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json");
request1.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var stream = new StreamWriter(request1.GetRequestStream()))
        {
          var shareMsg =
                  new
                  {
                      comment = "hello user",
                      content =
                          new
                          {
                              title = "Api post call"

                          },
                      visibility = new { code = "anyone" }

                  };

            string s = shareMsg.ToString();
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(shareMsg);
            stream.Write(json);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }
 WebResponse webResponse = request1.GetResponse();
 Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
 var reader1 = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string response1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have successfully done it with php

first you array should be like this

```
$data = [
        'content' => ['title' => 'go ahead BD Team', 
                     'description' => '#riseofthetiger',
                     'submittedUrl' => 'http://yourapp.dev', 
                     'submittedImageUrl' => 'http://yourapp.dev/image.jpg'
                   ],
        'comment' => 'Bangladesh vs India',
        'visibility' => ['code' => 'anyone']

    ];
```

and your header should like this

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'x-li-format' => 'json',
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

auth url :https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization/?client_id=""&redirect_uri=""&response_type=code&state=""&scope=w_share

```
      public String LinkedINAuth(string code, string state)
            {
                string authUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";

                var sign1 = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl + "&client_id=" + apiKey + "&client_secret=" + apiSecret + "&state=" + state;
                var sign = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code) + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(redirectUrl) + "&client_id=" + apiKey + "&client_secret=" + apiSecret + "&state=" + state;

                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                                     | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(authUrl + "?" + sign1) as HttpWebRequest;
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.Host = "www.linkedin.com";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

                String postData = String.Empty;
                byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

                dataStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();


                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                String returnVal = responseReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
                responseReader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                var stri = redirectUrl;
                retval = returnVal.ToString();
                var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accountdsdsd>(retval);
                TokenGlobe = objects.access_token;
                var SentStatus = PostLinkedInNetworkUpdate(TokenGlobe, "Hello API");
                return TokenGlobe;

            }
  public bool PostLinkedInNetworkUpdate(string accessToken, string title, string submittedUrl = defaultUrl, string submittedImageUrl = defaultImageUrl)
        {
            var requestUrl = String.Format(linkedinSharesEndPoint, accessToken);
            var message = new
            {
                comment = "Testing out the LinkedIn Share API with JSON",
                content = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {   { "title", title },
        { "description", description},
        { "submitted-url", submittedUrl },
        {"submitted-image-url" , submittedImageUrl}
    },
                visibility = new
                {
                    code = "anyone"
                }
            };

            var requestJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);

            var client = new WebClient();
            var requestHeaders = new NameValueCollection
{

    {"Content-Type", "application/json" },
            {"x-li-format", "json" }

};
            client.Headers.Add(requestHeaders);
            var responseJson = client.UploadString(requestUrl, "POST", requestJson);
            var response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson);
            return response.ContainsKey("updateKey");
        }
         public class Accountdsdsd
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
    }
    }

}
```